# Are the SPECIAL video clips available to view other than during game loading?

Tags: fallout-4

I'd like to view the S.P.E.C.I.A.L. video clips that are randomly shown during the initial game load.  Are they available to view elsewhere in the game?

Comment: If nowhere else, you can definitely find them on YouTube

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no way to view the videos from within the game, other than waiting for them to randomly display during the game load.  Other posts refer to the Bethesda YouTube channel:

https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSHdOA4o6T_c5iqXrXBIchAy78lPpZ9QY